# Repeating sequences in R

Tags: r, loops, sequence

I want to generate a vector of the the numbers `(1:5)`, `(1:5)+45` and so on

```
    nums <- seq(1,22500,45) 
    rws <- c(1:5)
    nums2 <- nums - 1
    for (i in nums2[2:500]){
    rwsx <- append(rws, rws+i)
    rwsx}
```

But the loop just stores the most recent append and I get:

```
1     2     3     4     5 22456 22457 22458 22459 22460
```

Comment: You mean something like `outer(nums, 0:4, "+")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `outer`. Try:

```
> nums <- seq(1, 22500, 45)
> out <- outer(nums, 0:4, "+")
> head(out)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]   46   47   48   49   50
[3,]   91   92   93   94   95
[4,]  136  137  138  139  140
[5,]  181  182  183  184  185
[6,]  226  227  228  229  230
> tail(out)
        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[495,] 22231 22232 22233 22234 22235
[496,] 22276 22277 22278 22279 22280
[497,] 22321 22322 22323 22324 22325
[498,] 22366 22367 22368 22369 22370
[499,] 22411 22412 22413 22414 22415
[500,] 22456 22457 22458 22459 22460
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, a `matrix` is a vector with dimensional attributes. Matrices in R a generally constructed by column, so if you want to remove the dimensions and get a single vector in the row-wise order, then you need to `t`ranspose the matrix first.

```
> head(as.vector(t(out)), 16)
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5  46  47  48  49  50  91  92  93  94  95 136
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought the OP wanted a single vector which will be row1 of your output then row2, ...

Comment: @etienne, a `matrix` is just a vector with `dim`s.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
rwsx <- matrix(nums,500) %*% matrix(rws,1)

head(rwsx)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]   46   92  138  184  230
[3,]   91  182  273  364  455
[4,]  136  272  408  544  680
[5,]  181  362  543  724  905
[6,]  226  452  678  904 1130
```

Answer (score 1):

```
r <- 22500%/%45
m <- matrix(45*0:(r-1), r, 5)
m <- m+ col(m)
rwsx <- c(t(m))
```

or

```
r <- 22500%/%45
m <- matrix(45*0:(r-1), 5, r, byrow=TRUE)
m <- m+ row(m)
rwsx <- c(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

As oneliner:

```
as.vector(sapply(seq(by = 45, length.out = 10), function(x) x + 0:4))
```